# Asking questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Where do I ask the dummy questions without getting downvoted? I have real questions, but they are getting downvoted and put on hold without saying why.  All I get is the boilerplate answer.

Now my questions are disappearing.  I want to do things correctly.

Comment: Yahoo ansers or ask.com

Comment: @gnat you're right but I also expected this user is somewhat confused between all the sites, see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332852/why-was-post-placed-on-hold)

Comment: @rene I think [the answer over there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152067/165773) covers this confusion fairly well, including that bit about all sites. _"Just because you're new to programming doesn't make you an idiot. It just means you're, well... new to programming. I'm not sure why people show up on Stack Exchange and think that just because they're new to programming that somehow reading information in the FAQ or following the rules is somehow beyond them..."_ Poetry...

Answer (score 7):

> I want to do things correctly.

We really appreciate that. Thanks for trying to improve your posts.

You really should work on the quality of your questions. From the response you get from the community, your questions are not up to the quality the community expects.

Look for recent posts that got upvotes and answers and compare them to yours. Are your questions as clear as those others? Does your post show research effort? Maybe your question has been asked before, so are you doing enough to find the duplicate?

Those were a few pointers to get you on the way. Good luck reviewing your posts. If you think those questions can't be brought up to the quality or level of expertise we expect, maybe some other sites are a better target for you.