# Adding a new group of users for quality checking - Volunteers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just wondering: **how about adding a new group of people, similar to moderators?**

**Main objectives:**

- Let all questions from *new* users enter a *sandbox* whenever they
  are posted.
- This group of people, lets say volunteers(for now) can only view
  questions in sandbox.
- These people do quality control:

  - Remove obvious *bad* questions without people having to downvote like mad.
  - Edit the question so rest of the people, can answer it without having to worry about the question.

**Why would people volunteer?**

- Add reputation, badges for doing this.
- For their self satisfaction.
- ~ Put reason here as to why do people cv,delv,flag etc? ~

I hope the idea I am trying to convey is clear. Perhaps we could discuss upon whether this is required at all? and other related things like these:

*new* - people with reputation < 10, **or** 0 questions && reputation < 10 etc..

*bad* - spam, do not belong here etc.

*sandbox* - could be as simple as a tag. questions of which, are only visible to volunteers, and removing the tag would make it out of sandbox.

Comment: Why? What problem does this solve which the tools and systems already in place don't? What's wrong with current flags and downvotes?

Comment: Well, honestly, wouldn't people love answering questions with out having to worry about if it isn't properly formatted, asked etc.? I would love that because I have come across several (may be a few) questions that ask the same 'give me the codes' again, and again. Also, many comments are 'what have you tried?'

Comment: Related: [Would a grace period or a sandbox mode help introduce new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118733/would-a-grace-period-or-a-sandbox-mode-help-introduce-new-users)

Comment: See http://www.stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: @goldenparrot People should worry about asking good questions on their own. They shouldn't be allowed to post bad questions (in a sandbox) and get away with it because we volunteer even more of our time to filter out the bad ones. And given the often less than warm reception of our current filtering process, I don't see how that would be any different if a select few would disallow users from even posting a question on the "real" website.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I am differently opined now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know it existed. @Jim

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stackoverflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgator)

Comment: Why volunteers for now? What will they be later?

Comment: I already said, I am differently Opined now, I got the point. End of discussion(at-least for me). I shall not view this Question again. Ever.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How might the Staging Ground & the new Ask Wizard work on the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377768/997587)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There exists the [review queue](/review]) for

- first posts from new users
- late answers from new users
- Low Quality Posts
- suggested edits

Most people looking at the review queue are *volunteers* who do pretty much what you ask for. Don't think there's a need for something different