# Is there anywhere to get help wording a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Suppose I have a question in my mind that I think is answerable but because I don't already know the answer, I'm not sure how to express in a way that makes it clear and definitively answerable. I suspect that someone more knowledgable than me would understand what I'm trying to get at though and could help me word the question properly.

Is there a good place to find this sort of help?

Comment: Did you check the help center - it has a [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) document?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152329/adding-a-new-group-of-users-for-quality-checking-volunteers

Comment: @Oded The issue is, what if I already know I can't word a question to meet those standards but I suspect that with some back and forth, others could help me to do so?

Comment: There is always chat - rules are a lot more relaxed in chat and you can certainly ask for help in different chat rooms.

Answer (score 7):

I would check out the site's main chat room (or a room specialized in the subject you want to ask about, if there is one), and see if there is somebody around to help phrasing your question. This will work better on some sites than on others, because not all sites make regular use of chat. Still, even if the chat room seems empty, you can leave a message there and wait for a response.

The easiest way to get to the chat is using the Stack Exchange button in the top bar, it has a 'chat' link in it which will send you to the correct chat server and filter out the rooms specific to that site.

Comment: From the little I've seen, most chat rooms won't accept such requests. (Hence my suggestion)

Comment: I'm not sure about Stack Overflow, but most other rooms will accept those requests if the question is 'on-topic' for their room.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't such a place currently.

The only thing I can think of is trying to organize a dedicated chat room on Stack Overflow (or any other site actually) where users who are willing to help other users will be, and user who wants such help will first gain 20 rep (doable even without perfect wording, e.g. edits, answers) then join the room and ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

The way to receive such help is by asking the question in as good shape as you possibly can on a Main SE site and then watching it like a hawk so that, as soon as anyone makes a suggestion for improving it, you can act on it and try to win the race with any potential downvotes.

Do not be disheartened if it takes a few Q&As before your questions start to arrive in a form that meets the site standards.

If you encounter a question ban then treat it as an opportunity to read more questions to see how their phraseology might be applied to your questions.