# Should I ask for help to forming question in metas?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, per-site-meta

Sometimes I have a vague idea for a question, but asking it right away may result in a confusing or unclear question, or after receiving answers I realize that I haven't asked the right one. Sometimes this happens even when I have researched on it. In such case, is it OK to ask the community first to help me forming the question in metas? This will reduce the time for editing back and forth, or in the case of already getting answer, will reduce the time they have to edit theirs for me.

The question [Is there anywhere to get help wording a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298784) does not have answer about meta specifically. In chat you can only discuss with some people, while in metas it is less fleeting and will receive more attention. If that's a bad thing, then one can argue the opposite that discussing on closed questions should be happened in chat too, not metas.

Comment: PPCG have a sandbox for that purpose. But it is not a QA site. The good place is chat

Comment: `in the meta it is less fleeting` That's a *bad* thing here.  This isn't the type of thing that actually benefits people to have sticking around.

Comment: @Servy but one can argue that after being closed for any reason, asking for help should goes to chat as well. This is not what I see

Comment: Hang on, they're beta testing a new mentoring system for folks looking for help like you https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LV6vS6CdG8oZNUVc3FxA1CteVIr2Fa8dVI2yDHi83ts/edit#heading=h.dpqhsm81ur6e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.  That is not what site metas are for.  Metas deal with questions about site scope/practices or general management.  However, some sites explicitly make this possible.  Both [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) and my site, [CS Educators](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/the-question-sandbox), have made such activity possible.

(CS Educators also has a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60468/the-guidance-office) that subscribes to their sandbox where the potential question can be discussed, and a system of mentors who are virtually always present in the room.  It actually gets a fair amount of use, though less so for the last few weeks.)

There may also be other sites that have created similar spaces, but it is up to a community to create this possibility.  If the site you are interested doesn't have a question sandbox, you could always propose one.  *That's* a good use of a site meta :)